# Bootstrap 4 adding bg image

Tags: bootstrap-4

[I am using this template](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/4-col-portfolio/)

When trying to add a background image it is not shown. My complete custom CSS is:

```
body {
  padding-top: 54px;

  background: url(img/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  body {
    padding-top: 56px;
  }
}

.portfolio-item {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.pagination {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change from

```
 background: url(img/background.jpg)
```

to

```
 background: url("img/background.jpg")
```

if not check your path